# created a user with clusterMonitor and dbOwner role, but db.getRoles() shows enableSharding role

Tags: mongodb, permissions, users, role, mongodb-3.4

I created a user with full privileges in it's own database (`dbOwner`) and read-only access to administrative commands (`clusterMonitor`)

```
use customerdb           
(mongod-3.4.7) customerdb> db.createUser( { user: "customer",
...                  pwd: "customerpw",
...                  roles: [ { role: "clusterMonitor", db: "admin" },
...                           { role: "dbOwner", db: "customerdb" }] },
...                { w: "majority" , wtimeout: 5000 } )        
Successfully added user: {
  "user": "customer",
  "roles": [
    {
      "role": "clusterMonitor",
      "db": "admin"
    },
    {
      "role": "dbOwner",
      "db": "customerdb"
    }
  ]
}
```

Enabled auth and logged in with the new user. It's a Homebrew installed MongoDB single instance with latest release.

```
$ mongo -u customer -p customerpw localhost --authenticationDatabase=customerdb
```

Why `getRoles()` shows me `enableSharding` role? I didn't found explanation in [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/)

```
> db.getRoles(
...     {
...       rolesInfo: 1,
...       showPrivileges:false,
...       showBuiltinRoles: true
...     }
... )      
[
  {
    "role": "dbAdmin",
    "db": "customerdb",
    "isBuiltin": true,
    "roles": [ ],
    "inheritedRoles": [ ]
  },
  {
    "role": "dbOwner",
    "db": "customerdb",
    "isBuiltin": true,
    "roles": [ ],
    "inheritedRoles": [ ]
  },
  {
    "role": "enableSharding",
    "db": "customerdb",
    "isBuiltin": true,
    "roles": [ ],
    "inheritedRoles": [ ]
  },
  {
    "role": "read",
    "db": "customerdb",
    "isBuiltin": true,
    "roles": [ ],
    "inheritedRoles": [ ]
  },
  {
    "role": "readWrite",
    "db": "customerdb",
    "isBuiltin": true,
    "roles": [ ],
    "inheritedRoles": [ ]
  },
  {
    "role": "userAdmin",
    "db": "customerdb",
    "isBuiltin": true,
    "roles": [ ],
    "inheritedRoles": [ ]
  }
]
```

the privleges for enableSharding role

```
  {
    "role": "enableSharding",
    "db": "customerdb",
    "isBuiltin": true,
    "roles": [ ],
    "inheritedRoles": [ ],
    "privileges": [
      {
        "resource": {
          "db": "",
          "collection": ""
        },
        "actions": [
          "enableSharding"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "inheritedPrivileges": [
      {
        "resource": {
          "db": "",
          "collection": ""
        },
        "actions": [
          "enableSharding"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

I tested this in a sharded cluster on mongos with version:

```
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.version()
3.2.11
```

and also on MacBook with single mongod and version 3.4.7

I guess I am doing something wrong how I create users and grant roles?

Comment: Pure guess, if this a feature/exception with your version `3.4.7`. Generally mongodb recommends even versions for customers.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide See my edit. MongoDB recommends even version 3.4 not 3.5, but I doesn't matter whats behind 3.4.7 or 3.4.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that "role" : "enableSharding" for customerdb because of "role" : "dbAdmin". So, that use can shard customerdb, but nothing else.